# Signal initialization VHDL

Tags: vhdl, active-hdl

I have an entity which has this

```
TEMPERATURE: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
```

as one of the inputs and I need a signal that has the initial value TEMPERATURE.
In the entity architecture I've declared the signal

```
signal temp:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0):=TEMPERATURE;
```

but when simulating temp remains UU(unassigned). How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SackOverflow. We do not know what `TEMPERATURE` is and are missing a lot of context. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: At simulation startup, `TEMPERATURE` is all `'U'`. Thus, `temp` gets initialized to all `'U'`. `'U'` stands for uninitialized, not unassigned. You should either initialize `temp` from a (generic) constant or implement a flip-flop. Your current design will not synthesize as expected.

Comment: You find ALL the drivers on that signal and either initialise or disconnect them.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If this is your design, you shouldn't be initialising a signal from an input at all. So, instead of trying to initialise `temp` to `TEMPERATURE`, I would take a step back and consider what it is you are trying to achieve (and what hardware you expect to be synthesised).